# Are there introductions to mathematics through physics?

Tags: reference-request, physics

I'm studying mathematics through three books:

- [Calculus: Early Transcendentals, Stewart;](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/4_home.php/)
- [Discrete Mathematics, Kevin Ferland;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618415386)
- [Polynomials, Barbeau.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387969195)

I have also some invitations to mathematics which present a different perspective: Some introduce mathematics through combinatorics, some introduce mathematics through set theory, etc.

Are there introductions to mathematics through physics?

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing. Combinatorics and set theory are parts of mathematics, so what do you really mean by "introducing mathematics through combinatorics/set theory"?

Comment: It's made to introduce mathematics, but it will take you to a specific field, in the case: Combinatorics and Set Theory. Mathematics introductions could leave you in a broad range of fields.

Comment: Still confusing!

Comment: I have nothing to say.

Comment: Combinatorics, set theory and logic  are the foundations of mathematics so that's why should any one starting mathematics should learn them first as introductions to the world of maths

Comment: A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John L Bell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The books you mentioned are not really introductions to mathematics through that topic. Rather the topic itself is a branch of mathematics; for example, calculus. Physics uses much mathematics, and much mathematics is motivated by physical problems; for example, differential equations. Some universities have undergraduate math syllabuses that cover a lot of physics; for example, Cambridge. For a good overview of undergraduate physics with lots of mathematical material, you may see *[The Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465023827)* by Nobel prize winner Richard Feynman.

Comment: This seems to be incredible! Thanks.